Relabeling disparity as depth
I've removed a bogus camera configuration that was supposed to assign absolute depth to captured photos, in order to save on later conversion from what otherwise seems to be disparity. Now I'm left with corrupted data, that is, absolute depth pretending to be disparity.
Is there a way to relabel the depth data to what it truly is, kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32?
I followed this approach, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/creating_auxiliary_depth_data_manually, by creating a new instance of AVDepthData, but it doesn't seem to enable saving camera calibration data, which I would also like to keep.
